# matlabpool(open...) hangs for 25+ minutes before starting workers

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

I've recently experienced an issue where the command `matlabpool('open', 'local', 8)` hangs for about 27 minutes before starting the workers. During the delay the Windows task manager shows a single MATLAB.exe process consuming zero CPU, no changes in memory usage or PF Deltas and less than 25% of physical RAM is being used.

I've tried entering `distcomp.feature( 'LocalUseMpiexec', false)` and `matlabpool close force local` before the open command but still have the issue. Until recently the open command would only take a minute or two to complete. I've not made any configuration changes but work in an IT department managed environment so can't be certain what maintenance updates might have been made to the OS/AV/etc.

Can anyone identify why this hangup is occurring?

I'm using matlab version  8.1.0.604 (R2013a) with  Java 1.6.0_25-b0.  I've also seen the issue using Java 1.6.0_17-b04.  Running Windows 7 Enterprise  Version 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 Build 7601.  PC has Dual Intel Xeon CPUs (12 cores) with 24 GB RAM.

I single stepped using the debugger and determined there were no delays until it reaches a call to `cjsPrepareForSubmission` at line 507 in the CJSSupport.m file. If at that point I do a “step in” once there is no change in the display except the “execution pointer” changes from a green arrow to a white arrow. A second “step in” brings up the JobInitData.m file that contains the `class def (Hidden, Sealed) JobInitData`, which hides the actual implementation from view.

"Step In" 7 more times works without delays adding the variables `plainTextForBatchJob` and `plainTextForInteractiveJob` to the workspace. On the 8th "step in" the status indicated in the main matlab window goes to busy and stays that way for the 25+ minutes. After the status eventually changes to stopped in debugger, you can hit continue and the workers start up immediately and the process finishes without additional delays.

Call tree from open call to hidden problem area:

```
matlabpool(‘open’, ‘local’, 8)
Matlabpool.m   139: matlabpoolOut = MatlabpoolHelper.doMatlabpool(parsedArgs,parsedArgs.ActionArgs.Scheduler);
MatlabPoolHelper.m  137:  MatlabpoolHelper.doOpen(sched, parsedArgs.ActionArgs);
MatlabPoolHelper.m  363: client.start('matlabpool', parsedOpenArgs.NumLabs, sched, 'nogui', parsedOpenArgs.FileDependencies);
InteractiveClient.m 279:  submit(obj.ParallelJob);
Job.m 302: job.submitOneJob();
CJSCommunicatingJob.m 82: job.Parent.hSubmitCommunicatingJob( job, job.Support, job.SupportID );
hSubmitCommunicatingJob.m  27: jobSupport.prepareJobForSubmission( job, jobSupportID );
CJSSupport.m 507 : cjsPrepareForSubmission( job, obj, jobSId );
JobInitData.m 8:  (HIDDEN)
```

Answer (score 6):

Problem was due to an obsolete environment variable LM_LICENSE_FILE pointing to a PC that was no longer on the network.

Using process monitor; we have identified the issue in MATLAB. We were able to see MATLAB trying to connect to an ip-address on port 1717 over the 26-minute period. That ip-address ended up being the old location for the license server for another product, which was set via LM_LICENSE_FILE. Once we removed the LM_LICENSE_FILE environment variable the problem stopped (Our MATLAB is licensed via another method; license file in license directory).

Apparently MATLAB tries to first use any servers in LM_LICENSE_FILE, and has an extremely long timeout if the server cannot be reached -- ~26 minutes. After it times out then it searches through the other methods of locating a license definition and is then successful.

The problem can be duplicated by setting an environment variable  "LM_LICENSE_FILE=1717@137.400.200.1" The ip-address chosen is arbitrary, but shouldn't have a PC connected to it.